# LINQ EF C# Select

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to Linq and EF; my project is in MVC3.  I am tyring to do a Select, and would like to add (Where or if) to exclude a record when specific item value is less than 1.
Here is my script

```
.Select(item => new AreaModel  
        {
            ID = item.ID,
            Name = item.Name,
            PersonID = item.PersonID,
        }) ;
```

In this case if the PersonID is less than 1 exclude this record.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should basically end up with something like:

```
EntityObject.Where(x => x.PersonID >= 1)
    .Select(item => new AreaModel  
            {
                ID = item.ID,
                Name = item.Name,
                PersonID = item.PersonID,
            });
```

Comment: remove comma after item.PersonID

Comment: @Aaron, trailing comma's are syntactically permissible in C#.  i actually tend to do trailing commas when newing up anonymous types and using type initializers in case i come back and want to add another property set.  keeps me from forgetting to do it.

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point for LINQ are the 101 LINQ samples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746

Happy LINQ'ing

Comment: This would have been better as a comment

Answer (score 0):

insert `.Where(item => item.PersonID > 0)` before `.Select`.